# Add documentation to generics.RetrieveAPIView 'retrieve' method's query param

Tags: django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

I have a simple view which takes 'email' as a query param and I would like to have it documented in the OpenAPI autogenerated schema. So far I tried applying `method_decorator` together with `swagger_auto_schema` on the API View class definition, but without success:

```
from drf_yasg.utils import swagger_auto_schema
from drf_yasg import openapi
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator


@method_decorator(name='retrieve', decorator=swagger_auto_schema(manual_parameters=[
    openapi.Parameter('email', openapi.IN_QUERY, description="Email to be checked", type=openapi.TYPE_STRING)]))
class EmailCheckView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = EmailCheckSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        email = self.request.query_params.get('email', None)
        if not email:
            raise Http404
        return User.objects.filter(email=self.kwargs['email'])
```

the auto generated models contains only information on the body coming from the serializer. Any ideas what's wrong?

DRF: 3.12.2

drf-yasg: 1.20.0

My swagger schema is added in urls.py with:

```
from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view
from drf_yasg import openapi
schema_view = get_schema_view(
   openapi.Info(
      title="My API",
      default_version='v1',
      description="",
   ),
   public=True,
   permission_classes=[permissions.AllowAny],
)

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('docs/', schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
name='retrieve'
```

to

```
name='get'
```

---

```
@method_decorator(
    name="get", # change is here
    decorator=swagger_auto_schema(
        manual_parameters=[
            openapi.Parameter(
                "email",
                openapi.IN_QUERY,
                description="Email to be checked",
                type=openapi.TYPE_STRING,
            )
        ]
    ),
)
class EmailCheckView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = EmailCheckSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        email = self.request.query_params.get("email", None)
        if not email:
            raise Http404
        return User.objects.filter(email=self.kwargs["email"])
```

Note: I am not sure whether the issue belongs to `method_decorator(...)` or `drf-yasg` itself